# R Data.table assign new column with user defined function

Tags: r, data.table

I am concerned by the following example.

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)
table1 <- data.table(a=sample(10,5,TRUE),b=sample(10,5,TRUE))
function1 <- function(a,b){
  a*b+runif(1)
}
table1[,c:=function1(a,b)]
table1[,d:=unlist(mapply(function1,a,b))]
set(table1,NULL,"e",unlist(mapply(function1,table1[,a],table1[,b])))
table1
    a  b         c         d         e
1:  3  9 27.205975 27.176557 27.717619
2:  4 10 40.205975 40.687023 40.991906
3:  6  7 42.205975 42.384104 42.380035
4: 10  7 70.205975 70.769841 70.777445
5:  3  1  3.205975  3.497699  3.934705
```

I would like to use the syntax I used to create the 'column c' but the number generated by `runif(1)` is always the same when I use that syntax. I found 2 ways to solve the problem ('column d' and 'column e'), but I clearly prefer the syntax used for 'column c'. Anybody has a solution for me?

Thanks!

Comment: To generate as you did with column `c`, try switching to `runif(length(a))` inside your function.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm new here! I just edited my question.

Comment: This is a reproducible example, my problem is much more complex. The key of the problem is to find a way to call a random function which is not function of a nor b.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to use the length of the vector. All random generators in R need to know the number of draws to make...

Comment: In fact, 'a' is a list, 'b' is a list and I want to generate a weight for 'a' and 'b'. Should I use 40% of 'a' and 60% of 'b'. It is invariable of 'a' and 'b'.

Comment: I don't understand. You could modify your question to cover your real case. No real harm in editing your question if no one's started answering, I think. My guess, based on your last comment, is that you're after `table1[, newcol := ifelse( sample(0:1, .N, prob=c(.4,.6), replace=TRUE), a, b)]`..?

Comment: Thank you @Frank, I just realized I was wrong. Though the package was working line by line as SAS does. I should always use the syntax I wrote for column `d` to avoid problems.

Comment: Hm, I disagree about using the `d` syntax, but maybe I'm misunderstanding the case you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

In your *column c* syntax, `data.table` actually sends two vectors to `function1`, but `runif(1)` is just a number, which R converts to vector of the same value. To avoid this situation pass the length of the vector to runif function (or `runif(length(a))` as was suggested)

```
function1 <- function(a,b, N){
  a*b+runif(N)
}
table1[,c:=function1(a,b, .N)]
```

Other option would be to evaluate function by row (which I suppose you have in mind)

```
table1[, id:=.I][, function1(a,b), by = id]
```

But it's not very efficient